# How to free dynamically allocated memory upon return from a recursive function

Tags: generics, unix

everyone
I have a problem with a C program and was unable to solve it by googling around.
The C file is down below, and the problem is that I'm not able to free the dynamically
allocated memory upon return from a recursive function.
The program computes the factorial of an integer in the form of a string of digits,
performs each multiplication and display the result in the same fashion, (strings of digits).
It performs the job it was designed to do, and while I'm sure you guys would use better ways,
my problem is only the fact that I cannot free some of the allocated memory.
The culprits are 2 types of allocation:
  - the strings that I use to do 'n - 1' for each 'multiplication' (malloc)
  - the calls to realloc() to accommodate the growing resulting string.
If I try to free them during recursion, obviously all breaks there, so I have tried to
solve the problem by using a global **pnt to copy each allocated pointer during recursion

and free them upon return from 'fact()'; This works only if I calculate in advance the

total number of digits in the eventual factorial, and use it to allocate memory for both

'**pnt' and the result string, so 'realloc()' won't be called; a call to 'realloc()', results
in a crash because 'free()' won't be able to find some pointers on the heap.
Googling around I fond that recursive functions and globals don't mix.
Could some expert tell me if it's possible to do what I try to do and how?
I'm not a proper programmer, just trying to learn a bit of C; I can do the same job using
non-recursive code, but I wanted to try this way this time around. 
Thanks and regards Marian.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <ctype.h>  

#ifdef DMALLOC  
#include <dmalloc.h>  
#endif  

char *fact(char *n, int *sz);
char *mulstr(char *st1, char *st2, int *s);
char *subone(char *sb);
char *reverse(char *rv);

/* ************************************************************************ */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int l = 0;
  if(argc < 2 || !isdigit(*argv[1]))
    puts("\a\nWe need a number.");
  else {
    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    for(;;) {
      if(!*argv[1]) {
        puts("\n<Enter> another number.");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if(num < 0)
          return 0;
        while(getchar() != '\n');
      }
      system("clear");
      int s = 16;  /* The size whic will grow to the eventual length of n1!. */
      char *n1 = malloc(s);
      sprintf(n1, "%d", num);
      n1 = fact(n1, &s);
      l = strlen(n1);
      printf("%d! = %s\nused %d bytes\nis %d digits long.\n", num, n1, s, l);
      free(n1);
      argv[1] = "";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

/* Recursively computes N! in the for of string f. */
/* ************************************************************************ */
char *fact(char *f, int *s) {
  if(!strcmp(f, "1") || !strcmp(f, "0"))
    strcpy(f, "1");
  else {
    char *mone = malloc(strlen(f) + *s + 1000);
    if(!mone) {
      perror("Allocation mone");
      exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(mone, f);
    mone = subone(mone);
    if(f && *f && mone && *mone)
      f = mulstr(f, fact(mone, s), s);
    else {
      printf("ERROR\a empty string.\n");
      getchar();
    }
  }
  return f;
}

/* Multiplies a * b in the form of strings st1 and st2. */
/* ************************************************************************ */
char *mulstr(char *st1, char *st2, int *s) {
  char *m1 = st1, *m2 = st2, *p1 = NULL, *p2 = NULL;
  char **lines = NULL;
  char *swap = NULL;
  int i, j, k, l2 = 0, l1 = 0, cr;
  if(strlen(st1) < strlen(st2)) {
    m1 = st2;
    m2 = st1;                   /* Pointer to the short string */
  }
  l2 = strlen(m2);
  l1 = strlen(m1);
  if((lines = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * l2)) == NULL) {
    perror("Allocation lines 0");
    exit(1);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < l2; i++) {
    if((lines[i] = (char*)malloc(l1 + l2 + 2)) == NULL) {
      perror("Allocation 1");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  p2 = m2 + l2 - 1;
  i = 0;
  cr = 0;
  while(p2 >= m2) {
    int n2 = *p2 - 48, n5 = 0;
    j = 0;
    p1 = m1 + l1 - 1;
    cr = 0;
    while(p1 >= m1) {
      int n1 = *p1 - 48, n3 = n1 * n2 + cr, n4 = n3 / 10;
      n5 = n3 % 10;
      lines[i][j++] = n5 + 48;
      cr = n4;
      p1--;
    }
    lines[i][j++] = cr + 48;
    lines[i][j] = 0;
    for(k = i; k < l2 - 1; k++)
      strcat(lines[i], "0");
    lines[i] = reverse(lines[i]);
    for(k = 0; k < i; k++)
      strcat(lines[i], "0");
    i++;
    p2--;
  }
  if(*s < l1 + l2 + 2) {
    *s = l1 + l2 + 2;
    if((st1 = (char*)realloc(st1, *s)) == NULL) {
      perror("Allocation st1 re");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  memset(st1, 48, l1 + l2 + 2);
  *(st1 + l1 + l2 + 1) = 0;
  cr = 0;
  for(k = l1 + l2 - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    int dtot = 0, d1, d2;
    for(i = 0; i < l2; i++)
      dtot += (lines[i][k] - 48);
    dtot += cr;
    d1 = dtot / 10;
    d2 = dtot % 10;
    cr = d1;
    st1[k + 1] = d2 + 48;
  }
  st1[0] = cr + 48;
  st1[l1 + l2 + 1] = 0;
  if((swap = (char*)malloc(*s)) == NULL) {
    perror("Allocation swap");
    exit(1);
  }
  strcpy(swap, st1);
  while(*swap && *swap == '0')
    memmove(swap, swap + 1, strlen(swap));
  strcpy(st1, swap);
  free(swap);
  for(i = 0; i < l2; i++)
    free(lines[i]);
  free(lines);
  return st1;
}

/* Reverses a string of digits. */
/* ************************************************************************ */
char *reverse(char *rv) {
  int ln = strlen(rv);
  char *p = rv + ln - 1, *tmp = alloca(ln + 1);
  int j = 0;
  if(!tmp) {
    perror("Allocation tmp");
    exit(1);
  }
  while(p >= rv) {
    *(tmp + j++) = *p;
    p--;
  }
  *(tmp + j) = 0;
  strcpy(rv, tmp);
  return rv;
}

/* 'subtracts' 1 from a string of digits. */
/* ************************************************************************ */
char *subone(char *sb) {
  char *p = sb + strlen(sb) - 1;
  char *swap = alloca(strlen(sb) + 1);
  while(p >= sb) {
    int dig = *p - 48;
    if(dig > 0) {
      *p = dig + 47;
      break;
    }
    else
      *p = 57;
    p--;
  }
  strcpy(swap, sb);
  while(*swap && *swap == '0')
    memmove(swap, swap + 1, strlen(swap));
  strcpy(sb, swap);
  return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `fact`, save the returned pointer. Before the function returns, `free` the stored pointer in that function. Basically, for any memory you allocate, either free that memory in the same function that allocated it or return a pointer to that memory to the caller and make sure the caller frees it before it returns.